# What is the pdf and cdf of $aX^2+bX$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X$ is normally distributed, $X \sim N(0, \sigma) $, what distribution is $aX^2+bX$? Is there any way to express the cdf and pdf?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm.  Well, if $f(x)$ is a PDF of a variable $X$, then I think the variable $X^2$ has a PDF equal to $g(x) = (f(\sqrt{x})+f(-\sqrt{x}))/(2\sqrt{x}), x \geq 0$, and the variable $cX$ has a PDF equal to $h(x) = f(x/c)/|c|$.  Then you'd have to convolve the two parts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By completing the square, we obtain the random variable $\ a\sigma^2\left(\frac{X}{\sigma}+\frac{1}{2\sigma}\frac{b}{a}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}\frac{b^2}{a}$, where $\left(\frac{X}{\sigma}+\frac{1}{2\sigma}\frac{b}{a}\right)^2$ is [a noncentral chi-squared random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution)  with 1-degree of freedom and non-centrality parameter $\lambda=\frac{1}{4\sigma^2}\frac{b^2}{a^2}$.